# get value of mysql colum with numbers in name

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get a value of my mysql table.
the column name has got numbers.

```
$temp= array();
$sql = "SELECT `00003A` FROM `table`";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

    temp[] = $row->00003A;

}
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '00003' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' on line 19
```

This is line 19:

```
temp[] = $row->00003A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try save this value in a variable like:

```
$prop = '00003A';
     temp[] = $row->$prop;
```

Or get data with

```
temp[] = $row['00003A'];
```